# Android webview chromium exception - ContextResult::kFatalFailure: too few uniforms or varyings supported

Tags: java, android, google-chrome, kotlin, chromium

Hello i got this error on console only emulator, maybe sometimes real device

```
E/chromium: [ERROR:context_group.cc(455)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: too few uniforms or varyings supported.
```

when i try to use webview first its not get this crash
but back page back page and then go to the page which contains webview i get this error

looks like only got this error on emulator but maybe it can be real device.

webView.loadurl method crash

i try only load [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) and all parameters of webview commentlined,
but it didnt work

try catch doesnt work

how can i found the solution about this error or catch this error ?
because our application is crashed i dont want it

thanks for helping me

Comment: This seems like Android emulator error. When you switch "Use Host GPU" on, you may get this error. In order to switch it off, fo to emulator settings and set Emulated Performance - Graphics to Software - GLES 2.0. However, you won't have responsive emulator anymore. You can work on emulators with API level lower than 10, otherwise. Android emulators are generally inconsistent with new API levels. Proly they will release an update soon.

Answer (score 0):

webView.loadurl if it is invoked more than once then you will get this error, try to release webview instance or load empty url.

And it happens only in Android 11